# Two DIVs, same level, target only the first via CSS

Tags: css

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="irrelevant"></div>
...
<div class="div1"></div>
...
<div class="irrelevant"></div>
...
<div class="irrelevant"></div>
...
<div class="div2"></div>
```

I'd like to apply some CSS only to `.div1`, considering that it's on the same level as (not a children or parent of) `.div2`.

**EDIT: To bring some light in the issue: The first `div` is actually my website's logo and the second `div` is a navigation that MAY or MAY NOT exist depending on the page viewed. If the navigation is present, I need to display the logo in a different manner (resize it).**

Comment: Your question in unclear.

Comment: @j08691 What do you mean by "unclear"? I need to apply some CSS rules to `.div1`. The div's with the `irrelevant` class are not relevant to the question but have been put there to illustrate that there might be some elements before, after and in between the two DIVs which are involved.

Comment: use .div1 {} ? or where is your problem....

Comment: Either you are an extreme HTML/CSS novice (which is perfectly fine) or none of us understand your question...

Comment: See the edited question. This is not a trivial question. I know how to apply CSS to a div. The question is - how to apply it **only** when the DIV is followed by another specific element.

Comment: You can't refer to elements based on the next ones ... you can refer to an element based on before elements but not after elements

Comment: see my answer... JS is needed

Comment: @WordPressDeveloper this isn't possible with plain CSS... you'll need some JS or jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS works as a cascade then you can never refer to elements based on what is next to them, just possible refer elements based on what was there before them.

> The subjects of a selector are always a subset of the elements matching the last simple selector

For this you may need the help of Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   if($('.div2').lenght > 0) {
     /*actions for .div1 here*/
   }
})
```

Comment: i wonder if that really is the problem as it is way to easy. but yeah, that's exactly what he asked for :)

Comment: @RiaElliger yeph i don't see any issue either but this is the answer. If you can vote for close the question as unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Since the class of both the divs are different, you can apply some specific rules to div1 by using class selector `.div1`

```
.div1 {
   /* div1 styles */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, so you want to apply css to div1 if div2 exists? CSS can't do that. You need JS. jQuery for example:

```
$('.div2').parent().find('.div1')
```

you can then apply the css directly or add another class ('div2exists') and add your style in your css-file

Comment: True, but he didn't mention anything about using jQuery - just pure CSS

Comment: that's why I said that he needs it to acheive what he wants. It is just not possible with CSS. Never, ever!

Answer (score 1):

Though there's a way doing this in CSS, I personally would not recommend that.

It will only work if we assume we have a fixed number of div elements inside some ".container" div. And this number is 6, 2nd is the logo (also it is 5th counting from the end), 5th is the navigation.

```
.container {}
.container .logo {}
.container .navigation {}

.container div:nth-child(2):not(:nth-last-child(5)).logo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.container div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(5).logo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

- The first rule is for the logo *with* navigation
- The second rule is for the logo *without* navigation

Again don't do this, CSS is not designed for that.

Comment: *don't do this* then why you post this have you tried this code?? or just came from toughts

Comment: sure, the code works. and it answers the asked question. the reason I don't recommend using it because the author wants to use a tool not designed for the task. though it is still possible with such kind of workaround, which maybe helpful for understanding it.

Answer (score -4):

You basically want to select a sibling, you will find a detailed post in this link [CSS Tricks - Child and Sibling Selectors](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

```
.div1 ~ .div2{
   Do your stuff here
}
```

This chunk will only take place if .div1 exists in your markup, is that what you wanted?

**Edit:**
I've noticed that your desired selector precedes the other one, this code will only work if the desired selector in this case .div1 is after .div2 .. CSS doesn't have that you will have to use jQuery

Comment: he wants to target div1, not div2 :)

Comment: Even with your comment you're wrong *if the desired selector in this case .div1 is after .div2* you aren't selecting div1 you're selecting div2 if is right after div1